# I am trying to use web scraper to login from https://angel.co/login

Tags: python, scraper

I am trying to use web scrape login from a website https://angel.co/login

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
USERNAME = "hide"
PASSWORD = "hide"
LOGIN_URL="https://angel.co/login"
def angel():
    sess=requests.Session()
    headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"}
    html = sess.get("https://angel.co/login",headers = headers).text
    bs= BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
    _xsrf = bs.find("input",attrs={"name":"authenticity_token"}).get("value")

    data={
      "authenticity_token":_xsrf,
      "email":USERNAME,
      "password":PASSWORD,
    }

    response = sess.post(LOGIN_URL,data =data,headers = headers)

    print (response.text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   angel()
```

I think I have an error about data.

```
    data={
      "authenticity_token":_xsrf,
      "email":USERNAME,
      "password":PASSWORD,
    }
```

May I ask what should I put info inside data?